# Elastic Search Fuzzy Search root and nested fields

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, mongoose, fuzzy-search, mongoosastic

I am new to Elastic Search and facing a couple of issues when querying. I have a simple Mongodb database with collections of cities and places of interest. Each collection has a cityName and other details like website etc, and also a places object array. This is my mapping;

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "cityName": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "phone": {
                "type": "keyword"
            },
            "email": {
                "type": "keyword"
            },
            "website": {
                "type": "keyword"
            },
            "notes": {
                "type": "keyword"
            },
            "status": {
                "type": "keyword"
            },
            "places": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                    "name": {
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    "status": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "category": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "reviews": {
                        "properties": {
                            "rating": {
                                "type": "long"
                            },
                            "comment": {
                                "type": "keyword"
                            },
                            "user": {
                                "type": "nested"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need a fuzzy query where user can search both cityName and places.name, however I get results when I search a single word, adding multiple words return 0 hits. I am sure I am missing something here because I started learning elastic search 2 days ago. The following query returns results because I have a document with `cityName: Islamabad` and `places` array having objects that have the keyword *Islamabad* in their `name`, in some `places` the keyword *Islamabad* is at the beginning of the `place.name` and in some `places` objects it might be in the middle or end

***This is what I am using : Returns results when only one word***

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
              "fuzzy": {
                "cityName": "Islamabad"
              }

        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "places",
            "query": {
              "fuzzy": {
                "places.name": "Islamabad"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Adding another word, say, `club`, to the above query returns 0 hits when I actually do have places having names `Islamabad club` and `Islamabad Golf club`

***Problem***
The search query is sent from an app and so it is dynamic, so the term to search is same for both `cityName` and `places.name` AND `places.name` doesn't always have the `cityName` in it.

***What do I need exactly??***
I need a query where I can search cityName and the array of places (only searching places.name). The query should be of Fuzzy type so that it still returns results if the word `Islamabad` is spelled like `Islambad` or even return results for `Islam` or `Abad`. And the query should also return results for multiple words, I am sure am I doing something wrong there. Any help would be appreciated.

**P.S : ** I am actually using MongoDB as my database but migrating to Elastic Search ONLY for improving our search feature. I tried different ways with MongoDB, used the `mongoose-fuzzy-searching` npm module but that didn't work, so if there's a simpler solution for MongoDB please share that too.

Thanks.

**EDIT 1:**

I had to change the structure (mapping) of my data. Now I have 2 separate indices, one for cities with city details and a `cityId` and another index for all places, each place has a `cityId` which will be used for joining later if needed. Each place also has a `cityName` key so I will only be searching the places index because it has all the details (place name and city name).

I have a city including the word `Welder's` in it's name and also the some places inside the same location have the word `Welder's` in their name, which have a `type:text`. However when searched for `welder` both of the following queries don't return these documents, a search for `welders` OR `welder's` does return these documents. I am not sure why `welder` won't match with `Welder's*`. I didn't specify any analyzer during the creation of both the indices and neither am I explicitly defining it in the query can anyone help me out with this query so it behaves as expected:

***Query 1 :***

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "name": {
                            "query": "welder",
                            "fuzziness": 20
                        }
                    }
                },
                 {
                    "match": {
                        "cityName": {
                            "query": "welder",
                            "fuzziness": 20
                        }
                    }
                }

            ]
        }
    }
}
```

***Query 2 :***

```
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "name": {
                "query": "welder",
                "fuzziness": 20
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the fuzzy query is meant to be used to find approximations of your complete query within a certain distance :

> To find similar terms, the fuzzy query creates a set of **all possible
>   variations**, or expansions, of the search term within a specified edit
>   distance. The query then **returns exact matches** for each expansion.

If you you cant to allow fuzzy matching of individual terms in your query your need to use a match query with the fuzziness activated.

```
POST <your_index>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "cityName": {
              "query": "Islamabad golf",
              "fuzziness": "AUTO"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "places",
            "query": {
              "match": {
                "places.name": {
                  "query": "Islamabad golf",
                  "fuzziness": "AUTO"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Reminder:** Fuzziness in elasticsearch allow at max 2 corrections per term. SO you will never be able to match `Islam` with `Islamabad` since there are 4 changes between those terms.

For more information on distance and fuzziness parameters please refer to this documentation page [fuzziness parameters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#fuzziness)